# unable to login to ubuntu one files with samsung galaxy tab

Tags: ubuntu-one, login, android, samsung

When I try to log on to the ubuntu one files app on my samsung galaxy tab I get the response

```
org.apache.http.client.httpresponseexception: UNAUTHORIZED
```

I'm trying to log on using my wifi, the app works on my android mobile, the tab shows under my applications page on the webpage and is listed as granted, I have uninstalled the app and reinstalled it again.

Is there something I can do to make the app work on my tab?

Comment: I had that problem too on 10.1.
For some reasons I don't know it was fixed automatically when I uploaded a picture from the gallery to ubuntu one.

Comment: Hey!

I have the 10.1 as well. And it worked for me too! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did as user25188 said. And now it works without any problem.

Solution:
Upload a picture from the gallery from the tab to make the
app work normally.